# How can I connect 2 computers running Windows 7 directly through wifi?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, connection

I just bought a new computer and I have a lot of files to transfer. Both computers are connected to my wifi router but it takes way too much time this way (estimated to take more than a day).

I'd like to connect the 2 computers directly using wifi but without using the router. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: @Phoshi: thanks for fixing the errors, my spell checker was a little off ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've not done it myself, but Windows 7 supports this.  Go to the Network and Sharing Center, click on Setup a new connection or network and the last option on the window that pops up is setup a wireless ad-hoc network.

You should be able to run that on both systems and get them to connect.

**Edit after reading the real problem**

Connect them with an Ethernet cable.  The ad-hoc may be faster, but that that much faster (unless ad-hoc will get you 802.11n and the router is 802.11g).  The best you could hope for is half-a-day  If at least one of the laptops has gigabit ethernet, then you don't even need a cross-over cable, it will auto-detect.

Comment: I managed to connect them using this method. It's still going to take some time but it' already 5 times faster than going through the router. Thanks.

Comment: Good to hear, @Julien. Could you let us know if you used the ad-hoc method @shf301 described, or an Ethernet cable?

Comment: I used the ad-hoc method. It's really easy to set up, just go to the Network and Sharing Center, then 'Add a new Connection or Network', choose the 'Wireless ad-hoc' option and follow the steps. The connection will be dismissed once all clients have disconnected from it.

Answer (score 3):

I may be wrong but I think your router is not the bottleneck, but rather the Wifi bandwidth itself is.

You may find it easier (read: *much* faster) to install the source HDD in the new machine as a secondary drive and copy the files directly, sans network impediments.

EDIT: This may be easier said than done, however, if one or both machines are laptops.

Comment: Indeed, both machine are laptops^^

Answer (score 1):

Get an Ethernet [**CROSSOVER**](http://www.amazon.com/gp/search/ref=sr_nr_i_0?rh=i%3Aelectronics%2Ck%3Acrossover+ethernet+cable&keywords=crossover+ethernet+cable&ie=UTF8&qid=1258459773) Cable/Adapter. Even if you could connect them via wifi, it'll take way too long. [How to connect 2 computers without a router](http://www.labnol.org/software/connect-computers-without-router/11049/).

Comment: @Julien doesn't say one way or the other, but he may also be required to buy one or two NICs to implement this if both machines don't already have NICs installed. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a "software access point" feature in Windows 7, so you can make one of your PCs pretend it's a router:

> netsh wlan set hostednetwork mode=allow ssid=MyNetworkName key=MyPassword keyUsage=persistent
>
> netsh wlan start hostednetwork

Answer (score 0):

Search 'Remote Desktop Connection' on youtube, the video shows you exactly what to do.

[link text](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pXYJWRsvg6E)

Or you can setup a network on windows 7.  youtube is great for showing you how to do this stuff.